# Tree model with poisson distributed response variable

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, cart

If I understand correctly the R tree model - library(tree) - can only be used if the response variable is normally distributed. Is there a way to create a tree model with poisson distributed response variables?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about R? In that case, this question would be off-topic here (add the [tag:R] tag and flag your question for migration to stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I am planing to d it with R. But at the moment is a general question. I do not understand if the response variable needs to be normally distributed when I plan to carry out a tree model.

Comment: Tree models, as far as I know, are typically not fitted by likelihood-based methods, so information about response distributio is not actually used.  So, you can just start with your Poisson data. The square-root variance-stabilizing transformations could be useful!

Comment: my understanding it that CART does not assume any specific distribution and so can be used with Poisson process. Issue could be with predictions that may have to be bounded it they lie outside the feasible range (negative values).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in previous comments: The CART algorithm (as implemented in `tree` or the `rpart` package) does not assume any likelihood for the data so that you can directly apply the algorithm to count responses as well. Using a transformation such as the square-root or continuity-corrected logs (`log(... + 0.5)`) or something similar might yield better results, though. It stabilizes the variances and avoids negative predictions (that would not be meaningful for count responses).

However, there are also model-based recursive partitioning algorithms that combine the nonparametric idea of recursive partitioning with formal parametric models. Prominent examples from the statistical literature are GUIDE introduced by Loh (2002, *Statistica Sinica*, **12**, 361-386) or MOB by Zeileis *et al.* (2008, *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **17**(2), 492-514). The latter is implemented in R in the general `mob()` function from the `partykit` package with a convenience interface `glmtree()` for GLM-based trees. The latter can also be used in combination with `family = poisson`.

A simple example is the following. (Note that the Poisson assumption does not really make sense but the data is used for simplicity anyway.)

```
## Poisson GLM tree with constant fit (~ 1) in each segment (~ speed)
library("partykit")
m <- glmtree(dist ~ 1 | speed, data = cars, family = poisson)

## visualize constant-fit tree
plot(as.constparty(m))

## scatterplot with fitted mean
plot(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
lines(fitted(m) ~ speed, data = cars, col = "slategray", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

[image]